# SQL 'case when' in hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, case, hibernate-criteria

How can I tranform the following query to a hibernate Criteria?

```
select pr_name, count(*) from (select (case when serv.type=xyz then serv.nameA else serv.nameB end) as pr_name from db.serv serv where serv.date is null group by pr_name;
```

I have got the following to handle the rest (except for the **case** part)

```
currentSession.createCriteria(StoredData.class)
  .setProjection(projectionList()
    .add(groupProperty("pr_name"), "pr_name")
    .add(rowCount(), "count"))
   .add(isNull("date"))
   .setResultTransformer(new PrCountTransformer())
   .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another property `prName` in `StoredData` and define this "case" part with pure sql using annotation `@Formula`.