# SQL case when in Hibernate criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How can I create `case when then else` using Hibernate criteria?
My SQL is like that:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EPS.RFQCORRIGENDUM 
        WHERE RFQID=A.RFQ_ID AND STATUS='FINAL') > 0 
    THEN 'YES' 
    ELSE 'NO' 
END) AS CORRIGENDUMISSUED
```

Comment: Why don't you just execute the count query and then render yes or no inside your Java code?

Comment: Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515868/sql-case-when-in-hibernate-criteria